# Gradle: Trying to build an *.so yields nothing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Gradle, especially with regards to the C/C++ build.  I'm trying to translate SCons into Gradle.  I have directory common/src which contains all the *.cc and *.h files.  The build.gradle consists of the following:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply from: './gradle.properties'
model {
    components {
        common(NativeLibrarySpec)
     }

     binaries {
         withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
            if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.windows) {
                cppCompiler.args '/MT', '/ZI'
            }

            if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.linux) {
                cppCompiler.args '-c', '-g', '-fPIC'
                linker.args '-pthread'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build .so, but nothing is produced, not even an error.

```
./gradlew commonSharedLibrary

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```

What am I missing?
Where can I find some C/C++ documentation and examples?

```
$ ../gradlew -version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation 25.151-b12)
OS:           Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually declared the source of what the Gradle script will be building

In the `components {}` scope you basically say that you are building a Library called Common ... this basically generates the `commonSharedLibrary` tasks ( which doesnt actually do anything)

If you called your component `tada(NativeLibrarySpec)` it would generate the corresponding  `tadaSharedLibrary`

inside the  `components {}` you need to declare the `source{}` of what you are building

```
main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
        sources {
            c {
                source {
                    srcDir "src/source"   <---- replace where your source is 
                    include "**/*.c"   <------ tells it to compile all c files in dir 
                }
               exportedHeaders {   <----- include files for the project
                       srcDirs  "include"
               }

            }
        }
```

Reading thought the documentation for the [Building native software](http://softwarehttps://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html) and looking at the examples I think would help you a ton